# How to add an imaginary element in anuglar 2 that takes a CSS class but doesnt get added in DOM

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to group a bunch of divs inside a container. The container should be able to take a CSS Class but shouldnt get added in DOM.
 
PS : I tried using ng-container but couldn't add CSS Class to it.

I want something like this :

```
<some-container class="s-check">
   <Div> line1 </div>
   <div> Line2 </div>
</some-container> 



@media(max-width : 768px) {
    .s-check {display : none }
}
```

to render the following in DOM :

```
<div> Line1 </div>
<div> Line2 </div>
```

and the CSS class s-check to be applied on the divs.

Comment: If its not added to the DOM, why give it a class in the first place?(since you won't be able to use that class) Maybe you can tell us what & why you are trying to do, so we can suggest a better way

Comment: You've got `<ng-container>` to help with one of your needs. But adding the class is not doable. By my knowledge, your combination of requests are not possible

Comment: You want to add a class to a parent container, to be used to style its child?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa - I want to hide and show the divs using media queries.And I cant group them in span coz it inline and grouping it inside div distorts my css.So I want some imaginary element to group i .

Comment: Ok, so can you tell exactly how do you want your divs to behave for different media sizes?

Comment: Show on screen size only greater than 768px.

Comment: Itseems very straight forward then, can you update what CSS have you tried so far